# Mean-square convergence of maximum likelihood estimators: Examples?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, convergence, estimators, consistency, point-estimation

From what I've gleaned from the literature, Cràmer, in his 1947 monograph *Methods of Mathematical Statistics*, proved convergence in probability of an MLE under certain regularity conditions. Subsequently, Wald, in a 1949  *Annals of Mathematical Statistics* paper, proved strong convergence under different regularity conditions. The methods introduced in both of these works have been extended over the years. As far as I can tell, though, the conclusions are always either convergence in probability or strong convergence of an MLE.

What I'm wondering is: Are there results under which regularity conditions on likelihood functions, log-likelihood functions, and their derivatives imply **mean square** (i.e., **$L^2$**) **convergence** of MLEs?